# Change Add to cart button to Preorder on select

Tags: php, magento

i have a small trouble to get working a php and jquery for magento to change button from add to cart to preorder if an option is selected on configurable selected product.

The php to check if one of the simple children products from configurable has the option selected.

```
<?php
$conf = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->setProduct($_product);
$col = $conf->getUsedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFilterByRequiredOptions();

$productMap = array();
foreach($col as $simpleProduct){
    $productMap[$simpleProduct->getId()] = $simpleProduct->getAttributeText('preorder');
    //$test = $simpleProduct->getId() && $simpleProduct->getAttributeText('preorder');
}
?>
```

result on echo: Preorder

Jquery to change the button if the selected product has the option.

```
<?php if($productMap) { ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        // On document ready hide the button to preorder first
        jQuery("#addtopreorder").hide();
        jQuery("#addtocart").show();
        jQuery("#<?=$productMap ?>").change(function() { 
            // Hide the button to preorder on slect element change action
            jQuery("#addtopreorder").hide();

            // Get the value of selected option
            var optionValue = jQuery(this).attr('value');
            // Just a test to see if you're getting option value
            //alert(optionValue);
            // Get the content (aka inner HTML) of selected option
            var optionValueText = jQuery.trim(jQuery('#<?=$productMap ?> :selected').text());

            // Just a test to see if you're getting right selected option inner text
            // alert(optionValueText);
            // alert('Selected option has value: ' + optionValue + ' and inner text: ' + optionValueText);

            // Show the button based on selected value
            // Whatch out, case sensitive...
            if( ! optionValue ){ 
                jQuery("#addtocart").show();
            } else {
                jQuery("#addtopreorder").show();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved by SCP Simple Configurable Product. made by Organic Internet.

[Link to Extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simple-configurable-products.html)