# Change SKU on select product size Magento

Tags: php, magento

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change Add to cart button to Preorder on select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14523059/change-add-to-cart-button-to-preorder-on-select)

I have a small issue with my script to select the sku of every product on select.

The issue is that, if i add 2 drop-down options the jquery is matching the same id twice.
But if i have only 1 drop-down with color or size, the sku is mapping showing correctly.

My question is... how can i get the correct sku for the second color ?

```
    <?php
    $_product    = $this->getProduct();
    $_attributes = Mage::helper('core')->decorateArray($this->getAllowAttributes());
    ?>
    <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && count($_attributes)):?>
    <dl>
        <?php foreach($_attributes as $_attribute): ?>
        <dt><label class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $_attribute->getLabel() ?></label></dt>
        <dd<?php if ($_attribute->decoratedIsLast){?> class="last"<?php }?>>
            <div class="input-box">
                <select name="super_attribute[<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>]" id="attribute<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>" class="required-entry super-attribute-select"
                        onchange="return changeSku(<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>, this);">
                    <option><?php echo $this->__('Choose an Option...') ?></option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </dd>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </dl>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var spConfig = new Product.Config(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
    </script>


<div id="sku-container"></div>
<?php
$conf = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->setProduct($_product);
$col = $conf->getUsedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFilterByRequiredOptions();

$productMap = array();
foreach($col as $simpleProduct){
    $productMap[$simpleProduct->getId()] = $simpleProduct->getAttributeText('sku');
}
?>

<script type="text/javascript">

document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
  $("sku-container").update("<strong>SKU: </strong> ...");
});

function changeSku(confAttributeId, sel) {
    var productMap = <?php echo Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($productMap);?>;
    var selectedAttributeId = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
    if (selectedAttributeId) {
        var options = spConfig.config.attributes[confAttributeId].options;
        var productId = options.find(function (option) {return option.id == selectedAttributeId}).products[0]
        $("sku-container").update("<strong>SKU: </strong>" + productMap[productId]);
    } else {
        $("sku-container").update("<strong>SKU: </strong> ...");
    }
}
</script>
```

spConfig Result: `var spConfig = new Product.Config({"attributes":{"80":{"id":"80","code":"color","label":"Color","options":[{"id":"42","label":"Blue","price":"0","oldPrice":"0","products":["6873","6874"]},{"id":"46","label":"Green","price":"0","oldPrice":"0","products":["6881","6882","6883","6884","6885"]}]},"123":{"id":"123","code":"size","label":"Size","options":[{"id":"13","label":"4 UK","price":"0","oldPrice":"0","products":["6881"]},{"id":"12","label":"4.5 UK","price":"0","oldPrice":"0","products":["6873","6882"]},{"id":"11","label":"5 UK","price":"0","oldPrice":"0","products":["6874","6883"]},{"id":"10","label":"5.5 UK","price":"0","oldPrice":"0","products":["6884"]},{"id":"9","label":"6 UK","price":"0","oldPrice":"0","products":["6885"]}]}},"template":"#{price}\u00a0USD","basePrice":"489","oldPrice":"489","productId":"9844","chooseText":"Select\u0163i o op\tion...","taxConfig":{"includeTax":true,"showIncludeTax":true,"showBothPrices":false,"defaultTax":24,"currentTax":24,"inclTaxTitle":"Whit tax"}});`

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved by SCP Simple Configurable Product. made by Organic Internet.

[Link to Extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simple-configurable-products.html)