# Magento. Change "Add to cart" button to "Pre-order" button for configurable products

Tags: php, magento

Thank you in advance for any help (I first post my question [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/37245/change-add-to-cart-button-to-pre-order-button-for-configurable-products), but there is no reply for several days).

In Magento, I am looking to change "Add to cart" button to "Pre-order" button for configurable products which inventory qty is set to 0.

Using this [tutorial](http://tutorialmagento.com/how-to-change-add-to-cart-button-to-pre-order-in-magento), I managed to accomplish what I am looking for but as it seems this solution works for simple products only, not for configurable ones (or I missed something)

I looked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14523059/change-add-to-cart-button-to-preorder-on-select) post, where a person says that SCP Simple Configurable Product extension made by Organic Internet solved his issue. I am not sure how it helped him. I have this extension installed on my site. It seems that there is no option for changing button from "add to cart" to "pre-order" or anything like that. Perhaps I miss something.

Can anyone give me a hand in solving this issue or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial has a php condition which is looking for the Qty value. The problem is, with configurable products, you need to load the associated simple products in order to pull the Qty values.

**Suggestion:** have you tried using issaleable? This would only show the "Pre-Order" button if the product is NOT saleable.

```
<?php if( $_product->isSaleable() ): echo $addtocart; else: echo $preorder; endif; ?>
```

If you simple want ALL your configurable products to have the "Pre-Order" button regardless of inventory, one solution is to modify this Qty condition to only check if its a Configurable product or not instead. One way is to change all occurrences of this:

```
<?php if($_product->getStockItem()->getQty()>0): echo $addtocart; else: echo $preorder; endif; ?>
```

to this:

```
<?php if( $_product->getTypeId() == 'configurable' ): echo $preorder; else: echo $addtocart; endif; ?>
```

Here's an example of loading the associated simple products, in order to get the Qty values. This may not be needed since its more complex.

```
foreach ($_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getUsedProducts ( null, $_product) as $simple) {
     Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($simple)->getQty();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

inside your pordut/list.phtml , try checking the product type as shown

```
<?php if( $_product->getTypeId() == 'configurable' ): ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all go to app/design/frontend/[your-package]/[your-theme]/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml.
There you can code like:

```
<?php if($_product ->getTypeId() == 'configurable'): ?>
//Do your part
```

All the best